# python input parameters getting added

Tags: python

How do you add prompt parameter in the input function for python?

```
def getUserFileNameInput(self, s):
    FileName = input("Please enter the file name and path for " % s)

test = t()
test.getUserFileNameInput("my.txt")
```

**My current error :**

```
File "C:\Python34\try.py", line 13, in getUserFileNameInput
FileName = input("Please enter the file name and path for " % s)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't concatenating strings correctly, you have, at least, two ways to do it :

```
myNewString = "Here's my old string : %s" % oldString
```

*or*

```
myNewString = "Here's my old string : " + oldString
```

So in your example you should do :

```
def getUserFileNameInput(self, s):
    FileName = input("Please enter the file name and path for " + s)

test = t()
test.getUserFileNameInput("my.txt")
```

*or*

```
def getUserFileNameInput(self, s):
    FileName = input("Please enter the file name and path for %s" % s)

test = t()
test.getUserFileNameInput("my.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the python fomat with the C scanf function usage and missing the concatenate usage. You can just concatenate the two strings to get the prompt for input. I do not think that you need the format as long as s is already a string (as you put in the call). If you wanted to pass a value (like an integer) you could always use `string(s)`. However, I thing a plain concatenate would be better.

```
def getUserFileNameInput(self, s):
    myprompt = "Please enter the file name and path for " + s
    Filename = input(myprompt)
    return Filename

myentry = test.getUserFileNameInput("my.txt")
print myentry
```